# Flutter go_router parameters within ShellRoute not working

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-go-router

I am using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) and need have setup a `ShellRoute`. It is working fine so far. Now one of the `routes` inside that `ShellRoute` should have a route with `params`. And I can not make it work..

This is my setup:

```
final rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class AppRouter {
  static final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  static final router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: IntroView.path,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
    routes: [
      ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
        pageBuilder: (context, state, child) {
          return NoTransitionPage(
            child: ScaffoldView(
              initLocation: state.location,
              child: child,
            ),
          );
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            name: ProjectsView.name,
            path: ProjectsView.path,
            parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              return const FadePageTransition(
                page: ProjectsView(),
              );
            },
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
                path: 'projects/:projectTitle',
                pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                  return FadePageTransition(
                    page: ProjectDetailScaffold(
                      project: Projects.values.byName(
                        state.params['projectTitle']!,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ...
```

And I am trying to `push` to `ProjectDetailScaffold` like this:

```
rootNavigatorKey.currentContext!.push(
              '/projects/wishlists',
            );
```

But I get an `error` that no route exists for `/projects/wishlists`...

What am I missing here?

Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by myself:

The problem was that I specified `path` of the subRoute wrong. I added it's parent path as well when I only need to add `:projectTitle`. Here is the working solution:

```
  GoRoute(
    parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
    path: ':projectTitle',
    pageBuilder: (context, state) {
      return FadePageTransition(
        page: ProjectDetailScaffold(
          project: Projects.values.byName(
            state.params['projectTitle']!,
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```